# Why does Payara / Glassfish 4.1 websocket return 404 error?

Tags: jakarta-ee, websocket, glassfish, glassfish-4.1, payara

I try to set up a websocket with Payara Java EE application server and followed largely on [this tutorial](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/HomeWebsocket/WebsocketHome.html#).

Everything seems up and running, but I always get this nasty error message:

```
websocket error InvalidResponse(HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found)
```

I tried to connect to the websocket with my iOS device by using the [SwiftWebSocket library](https://github.com/tidwall/SwiftWebSocket) and also by a simple HTML/Javascript websocket client. Both approaches return exactly the same error mentioned above.

My Glassfish 4.1/Payara server is running on a separate Ubuntu Server machine within my LAN. There's nothing logged to the server log. I use the following URL to try to connect to the webservice:

```
ws://192.168.1.152:8080/MyWebSocket/endpoint
```

Where `MyWebSocket` is my Java EE project name in Netbeans IDE and the endpoint is defined on my websocket class with `@ServerEndpoint("/endpoint")`.

Any ideas why I get the `404` error? Any settings that I have to change on my application server?

Comment: I did found the solution to the problem. I had to use `ws://192.168.1.152:8080/MyWebSocket-war/endpoint` instead of `ws://192.168.1.152:8080/MyWebSocket/endpoint`. In Netbeans IDE, this is defined in `web project properties` -> `Run` tab -> `Context Path`.

Comment: I would recommend you to use `wss://` instead of `ws://` so that the communucation is secure/encrypted.

Comment: Yes I did and it works fine too. Thanks.